# How to only get partial data set from firebase query

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2, firebase-security

I'm attempting to create a database of Users in firebase.

The structure is as follows:

```
users: {
    uid: {
        username: exampleName
        email: exampleEmail
        personalInfo: examplePersonalInfo
    }
}
```

Currently, I'm able to get the ENTIRE data object from the query I run by doing:

```
db.database.ref('users').orderByChild('username').equalTo('exampleName')
    .once('value').then(handler);
```

I want to query the database to make sure no other individual has that username, but the problem I'm running into is I get ALL the data for the specific uid.

I only need the username, and would like to establish rules where:

```
 personalInfo: {
    ".read" = "$uid === auth.uid"
 }
```

but

```
 username: {
     ".read" = true
 }
```

is this possible, and is there a solution here to only query and receive the username?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When a query returns a child node, that child node will contain everything underneath it.  You can't further filter the children to return.  In fact, with security rules, once you grant access to the client to a particular child node, the client has implicit access to *everything* under it.  You can't reject access to a child node of a parent node that you've already granted access.

If you need to limit the size of the result set by selecting only necessary children, you will have to duplicate the data into a structure that contains only the data needed for this particular query.  This is common in nosql type databases.  The upside is faster and smaller reads.  The downside is larger amount of storage, and you'll need to keep the duplicates in sync.

Comment: if the only node I need is "username" is there a way to query this and only receive the username node? Since right now I query the entire users table for the user node, can I query the entire users table for the users username?

Comment: My answer is trying to explain that you can't do that.